# SPD 2013 Foundation List workflow does not always fire on Item Change

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I have created simple List Workflow on document library using SharePoint designer, set the workflow to run on Item Created and Item Change.

I set Reviewer dropdown, this contains 3 reviewers emails(AD users), another dropdown contains 'UnderReview','Reviewed' option. When first time WF starts it runs fine. But when Reviewer edits the doc lib and selects the second or third Reviewer WF won't fire on ItemChange.

Please suggest where I am doing wrong?

**Edits**

My workflow look like this

[image: My WF look like this]

Comment: Have you handled the condition for the second and third option , Should you share workflow detail steps,

Comment: see the edits, I have added image

Comment: @M.Qassas please see the edits

Comment: Hi ,I am sorry I was not here , please check my answer ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workflow should be working properly, but your issue at the first `if condition` and `second else` that never reached .

where you are set `strEmail` to `current item:reviewer` , then check `if the email is not empty` , so it's never going to second else because the `strEmail` is not empty.

Try to remove **if condition** at `strEmail` is not empty , and make sure that the else condition for the second else is related to  `if itemreviwerstatus equal "status1"`

[image]

Comment: Awsome!!! I m wondering that why I did not not seen this. Anyway Thanks @M.Qassas